# How to set a variable to another instance by reference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

given the following code:

```
vars = instance_variables.map(&method(:instance_variable_get))
vars.each {|v| v = 123}
```

would that set @something = 123?

taking it a step further

is it the same if i have

```
vars = instance_variables.map(&method(:instance_variable_get))
vars.each {|v| doSomething(v) }

def doSomething(var)
  var = 123
end
```

how would i mutate var from inside a function?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're wanting to achieve, it's generally bad practice to change the value of a parameter, and in many cases not easily possible without a bit of a hack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test this in `irb` pretty quickly:

```
@something = 456
instance_variables
# => [:@something]
instance_variables.map(&method(:instance_variable_get)).each { |v| v = 123 }
@something
# => 456 (i.e. "didn't mutate @something")

def doSomething(var)
  var = 123
end
vars = instance_variables.map(&method(:instance_variable_get))
vars.each { |v| doSomething(v) }
@something
# => 456 (i.e. "didn't mutate @something")
```

[Object#instance_variable_set](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set), however, *does* change the value of `@something`:

```
@something = 456
instance_variables.each { |v| instance_variable_set(v, 123) }
@something
# => 123
```

Comment: but i'd also need to pass the key? for v and by key i mean instance var name?

Comment: Yeah, `v` in that last snippet is a symbol: `:@something`

Comment: To be precise, your approach still doesn't mutate the instance variable. It just sets it to a new value. When you say "mutate", generally people mean to change some aspect of an existing object without assigning a new one, i.e by preserving the `object_id` of the referenced object.

Comment: @HolgerJust: Really good point! Edited the answer to be more precise.

Answer (score 1):

Agreeing with pje, you probably should have tested this in irb, but I'm assuming you want to capture a setter for every instance variable, so I'd recommend something like:

```
setters = instance_variables.map{|v| lambda { |val| instance_variable_set(v, val) }}
```

then you can just do `setters[0].call(__VALUE__)` and it will set the value accordingly.

What is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: it wasnt so much laziness, just curiousity of what the implications of why / how the pass through works etc.

Comment: i didn't really know about the mutations / instance_variable_set etc. I'll update my question to reflect more of that request for knowledge.